# how to connect to a mysql url from mac using mysql-client

Tags: mysql, macos

I used `brew install mysql-client' and it installed the client but I have no access to manual help on this. What is the way to connect with a url mysql://db.dev.dev.ms-df-cloudrdbms.glb.us.net:3306/cx_cortex for instance ? Do I have to also install mysql server to connect or is there a client?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql client command is quite easy to use:

```
mysql -h mysqlhost.mycompany.com -u root -p db_name
```

> -h host
>
> -u user
>
> -p (input password by typing it or in the command line)

For help, you can try:

```
mysql --help
```